# Шар голубой

Tags: значение-слов

Здравствуйте!
Меня с детства озадачивали слова известной песенки "Крутится-вертится шар голубой, крутится-вертится над головой, крутится-вертится, хочет упасть..."
Сперва кажется, что речь о планете - "шар голубой", но почему же тогда он над головой и хочет упасть?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Барышень по ночам обычно воруют. Ночью на небе "голубым шаром" висит луна. А если от любви и страсти аж голова кружится, то эта луна и "крутится", и "вертится", и даже "упасть" хочет.

Кстати, в некоторых вариантах песни ночное светило называется и традиционным именем, в качестве свидетеля событий.

Comment: А  почему  про  надувной  шарик  никто  не  вспоминает ?  Они  же  были  уже  в  начале  века.

Answer (score 3):

В советские годы эта песня часто обсуждалась. В первоначальной версии "крутится, вертится шарФ голубой". Можно почитать об этом здесь http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B и на разных др.страницах

Answer (score 2):

В оригинале было "шарф". 
Стихотворение, положенное потом на музыку, было опубликовано за авторством некоего К.Р., в котором угадывался Великий Князь Константин (Романов).
Но, возможно, он не был первым автором, а лишь немного немного доделал более раннюю версию (предположительно - М.П, Вольпина), в свою очередь являвшейся аллюзией на романс "Шарф голубой" Н. А. Титова на слова М. А. Маркова.

В интернете полно ссылок.
http://nadezhdmorozova.livejournal.com/174162.html
http://www.historyonesong.com/2010/03/sharf_goluboi_1/
и проч.

(Пассажи типа *украинских "исследователей"-русофобов* оставляю на совести авторов; время у нас такое, чтобы даже в гипотетическом еврейском следе видеть происки древних укров-русофобов).

Авторы расходятся в некоторых деталях, но уж конечно ни к шару, ни к идишу, ни к елкам, исходный текст не имел.

Потом почему-то у шарфа потерялся последний звук... Видимо, длинные "вертящиеся" дамские шарфы вышли из моды, а потом и вовсе забылись как буржуазный пережиток...
А вот как соверешенно русский романс зазвучал вдруг на еврейский манер 
(о чем есть немного здесь http://www.sem40.ru/index.php?newsid=218052) - это загадка не для простых умов. Я совершенно не компетентен судить авторов подобных утверждений.

Answer (score 0):

Эта песенка перевод с идиша еврейско-ашкеназской народной песни "Где эта улица ,  где этот дом ?" . Про историю этой песни можете посмотреть видео на YouTube по ссылке [YouTube. Крутится , вертится шар голубой ... - народная песня российского шансона .](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdG8gPAa15g) (Примечание : это моё авторское видео , под другим ником .) Возможно , что  ШАР ГОЛУБОЙ это вольный перевод с идиша или какие-то издержки перевода .